# Path autocomplete does not work in PhpStorm

Tags: macos, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have clean install of the latest PhpStorm 2016.1.2 version running on OS X El Capitan. While code completion works perfectly, I can not use path completion at all. If I type `../` I expect to get files/folders suggestion from parent folder, but I only get message "no suggestion". Same thing happens if try relative or absolute paths or only file names without path.

Also if I type path by hand, I can not click on it with <kbd>cmd</kbd> and mouse. Path just does not get resolved.

The same code works perfectly with WebStorm on the same computer. Also it works on other identical computers with the same OS X and PhpStorm versions.

I tried clearing cache, creating new project, reinstalling PhpStorm, flushing all PhpStorm preferences (deleting files) but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

I found that path autocomplete does not work only when I use common.js `require` syntax. 
Installing `node.js` plugin to PhpStorm solved the problem.